# ServletRequest.getParameter() vs ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameter()

Tags: java, spring

What is an actual difference between `ServletRequest.getParameter()` and `ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameter()`. Is there any advantage of using a spring framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference at all between `ServletRequest.getParameter()` and `ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameter()`. The `ServletRequestUtils` class is useful when your parameters are of different type, you'll be able to get the parameter without the need to cast the return value and an `Exception` is thrown when the parameter have the wrong type. If all your parameters are `String`, I don't see the benefit of using `ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameter()` instead of `ServletRequest.getParameter()`.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/web/bind/ServletRequestUtils.html#getStringParameter%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20java.lang.String%29) :

> Parameter extraction methods, for an approach distinct from data
>   binding, in which parameters of specific types are required.